# PHP SimpleHTMLDom Extraction

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I want to get the name and URLs from the first column of the table at http://www.pferd-aktuell.de/fn-service/pferdebranchenbuch/kategorie-uebersicht/13/FN-Vereine AND THEN traverse through the NEXT button to get all such occurrences of the Names and their URLs from all available pages. I tried something like this and it does not output anything.

```
<?php

include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);

$url = 'http://www.pferd-aktuell.de/fn-service/pferdebranchenbuch/kategorie-uebersicht/13/FN-Vereine';
$html = file_get_html($url);
$file = 'Titels.txt';

    if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'a+')) {
        echo "Cannot open file ($file)";
        exit;
        } 
    else {
        for ($i=1; $i<=25; $i=$i+1)
        {
            $ret = $html->find('td[class]="withBorder bold"', $i);
            fwrite( $fp, $ret->plaintext."\n");
        }
    }
```

}

After extracting the Titel and URL, I plan on navigating through each of those URLs and be able to extract some divs from there too (like Ort, Email, etc).

Any sample code to get me started? Please :)

Comment: From the code you've posted above, you're definitely on the right track. Find the url that the Next button points to, and pass that to a function that extracts whatever you need from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find() call should probably be:

```
$ret = $html->find('td[class="withBorder bold"]', $i);
                                              ^---note the new location
```

As written, your is looking for any td which **HAS** a class attribute, followed by a nonsensical `=` html element.

Comment: Okay it worked now :) But the thing is... It defaces the special German Characters. Like these BERLINER KLEINPFERDEVEREIN E.V. FÃ¼r Zucht u. Sportm, GlashÃ¼tter PSV OberFr.dorf e. V. How do we retain the German characters?

Comment: Just noticed it also does not return all 25 but just the 11. I dont know why though. Still checking... Also how do I handle the pagination?

Comment: getting `Ã` in the output means you've got UTF-8 text being displayed as some other charset, probably iso-8859-1. make sure your entire rendering pipeline is set to utf-8.